# django admin base.css cannot be found

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, openedx

I have an openedx instance which works fine with just an strange issue. for those who aren't familiar with [openedx](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/) it's a learning management system written in django.

**The issue:**
trying to access django admin from http://mydomain.tld/admin shows the login page properly but with two static files, unfortunately one of them (base.f4e3330c1326.css) is not on the file system and the request for its loading ends with a `HTTP 404 Not Found` response.

looking at the static directory, there are 3 related files:

```
├── base.5af66c1b1797.css  
├── base.css  
├── base.d01c565630c2.css
```

caclulating the base.css md5 checksum:

```
user@host: ~$ md5sum /edx/var/edxapp/staticfiles/studio/admin/css/base.css
5af66c1b1797cb8f865b443cea0dcc17  /edx/var/edxapp/staticfiles/studio/admin/css/base.css
```

using django shell to retrive the path to the files:

```
>>> from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
>>> static('admin/css/base.css')
'/static/studio/admin/css/base.f4e3330c1326.css'
```

I have collected static files more than ten times but it doesn't fixed.

my similar instance somewhere else has not this problem and I'm realy confused with it.  could you please help me to debug this?

PS: I don't know about webpack but I think they started to use it recently and I think it should have some relation to my issue...

Comment: Did you change your "STATIC_ROOT", "STATIC_URL"? And maybe permission issues.

Comment: @IsankaWijerathne I didn't do so, but I'm sure it doesnt help; because all other static assets are loading properly

Comment: Did you check the permissions?

Comment: I mean folder permissions. But if you just follow Open edX guide, it should be ok.

Comment: @IsankaWijerathne surely its not a pemission issue, I have many reasons for that one of them: I've removed staticfiles directory entirely and recollect assets but the problem's still remained